# Is there a way to give permanent admin permissions to an application?

Tags: c#, windows, permissions, administrator

So I have made a program that requires administrator permissions every time you run it. Is there a way to give it permanent administrator permissions after you give the permissions once. So basically the first time you run the application, it asks for administrator permissions and if you run in a second time, it wouldn't ask for them again. Is this even possible at all and if so, can I do this programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: If that was possible...it would certainly be exploited by virus writers.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

The only thing you could do is implement parts of your program in a NT service. Set the service configuration to "start manually" and change the ACL to allow any user to start the service.

Your program would then use the service to perform the tasks that require elevation.

If you choose this route, you have to be careful so that you don't introduce security holes in the system. Only allow predetermined actions, not arbitrary commands nor write operations...